# What kind of larve is this? Found in shed on terracotta pot in Northwest Oregon

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this on a terracotta pot in my shed[image: larve in mud nest on terra cotta potenter image description here]

Answer (score 5):

They look like the nest and pupae of a mud dauber wasp; the [black and yellow mud dauber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_and_yellow_mud_dauber) is a common species to your area and elsewhere, though I can't personally identify the species clearly from the larvae themselves they certainly are consistent.

[A nice view of the nest building process](http://www.abundantnature.com/2012/08/mud-dauber-wasp-nest-part-1.html)

[image][image]

These wasps have a characteristic very skinny abdomen, and they pack their nests with spiders before laying an egg there. They aren't typically a bother to people because they don't have any communal nest to defend, except for building nests on troublesome places like [airplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birgenair_Flight_301).

Comment: This is a good ID, +1. I'm curious though -- was there anything specific that tipped you off in order to properly ID, or were you already familiar with this wasp?

Comment: @Charles Those nests are pretty distinctive, though I see the blue variety more often than the black and yellow where I am (OP's nest could easily be a blue mud dauber as well).